# Place td side by side in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
var data = [
   {Utente: "Teste", },
   {Utente: "Teste1", },
   {Utente: "Teste2",},
   {Utente: "Teste3", },
   {Utente: "Teste4", },
   {Utente: "Teste5", },
];

$(document).on('click', '.dad-inf', function(){

var linha = ``;

Object.keys(data).forEach(i=>{
Utente = data[i].Utente;

linha += `<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center text-muted">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item btn btn-warning histor-uten">
                  <div class="profile-photo-div" id="profile-photo-div">
                    <div class="profile-buttons-div">
                      <div class="profile-img-input" id="profile-img-input">
                        <label class="butttton" id="change-photo-label" for="change-photo">#${Utente}</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </a>
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </div>`;
   })
                  
   $("#tesssste tbody").html(linha);
 
});

$(function() {
    $(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      el = $(this).data('element');
      $(el).show();
      $("section > div").not(el).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="s105" data-element="#minhaDiv105" class="btn-show dad-inf">Utentes</a>

<section id="s105">
  <div id="minhaDiv105">
    <table class="tesssste" id="tesssste">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

I intended for the `td` to be side by side and not the way it appears.
This way, whenever you repeat a `td`, it always returns under the previous one and the objective is to return it side by side.
I'm using `<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">` to try to make the `td's` side by side. I've also tried putting it before the `table` tag, but the result is the same and not side by side.

I leave an example of how I want the result:

[image]

Comment: Your snippet does not have any utility classes. Did you mean to add bootstrap or tailwind?

Comment: @Michael M. Already added. I think that was it

Comment: i doubt that's the problem.  On each <tr> you only have 1 <td>.  Which <td>'s do you want to place side by side?

Comment: @DCR Yes, I intend to put it side by side. The amount of `td`, depends on the data returned from the database

Comment: i have no idea what you mean. can you estate the problem you are having? perhaps with here's what I'm getting and here's what I want?

Comment: @DCR The problem is that I want Test, test1, test2, test3, test4 and test5 to be side by side. And as is the code it always returns one under the other. Did you understand?

Comment: @DCR I leave an example in image of the result I want.

Comment: Why aren't you using flex or grid for your layout? Is there a specific reason you want tables?

Comment: @dale landry  I'm using a table, because then I have to get the id of the td I click on and if I use a div then it doesn't get the id of the div I click on. always takes only the first id returned

Answer (score 0):

just place the td's on one tr.  The comment above by Dale is excellent. If you use a div instead of a table, flex will make it a lot easier to manipulate your output.

```js
var data = [{
    Utente: "Teste",
  },
  {
    Utente: "Teste1",
  },
  {
    Utente: "Teste2",
  },
  {
    Utente: "Teste3",
  },
  {
    Utente: "Teste4",
  },
  {
    Utente: "Teste5",
  },
];

$(document).on('click', '.dad-inf', function() {

  var linha = `<tr>`;

  Object.keys(data).forEach(i => {
    Utente = data[i].Utente;


    linha += `
              <td class="text-center text-muted">
                ${Utente}
                
               </td>`;
  })

  linha += `</tr>`

  $("#tesssste tbody").html(linha);

});

$(function() {
  $(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).show();
    $("section > div").not(el).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
  padding:10px;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="s105" data-element="#minhaDiv105" class="btn-show dad-inf">Utentes</a>

<section id="s105">
  <div id="minhaDiv105">
    <table class="tesssste" id="tesssste">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```